# calling a constructor from a derived class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

Hi I have been trying to use my zero­parameter constructors to call my 
 SunkenObject constructor with initial weight values but for some reason i keep getting this error

`constructor` SunkenObject `in class` SunkenObject cannot `be applied to given types`;`

```
required: float
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This is my SunkenObject constructor:

```
public abstract class SunkenObject extends CatchableThing
{
   protected float weight;

   public SunkenObject(float w)
   {
     weight = w;
   }

  public float getWeight() { return weight; }

    public String toString () 
    {
        return (getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

and this is one of the objects (a rusty chain) that is extended by SunkenObject

```
public class RustyChain extends SunkenObject 
{

    public RustyChain (float w)
  {
    super(w);  
  }
   public RustyChain()
   {
     weight = 8.0f;
   }


}
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong because from my perspective nothing is wrong with the code. Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
public RustyChain() {
    super(8.0f);
}
```

`weight = 8.0f` doesn't call the super class constructor.

Comment: @user3330114 some time we just lost it.. :P :D even if it is just few steps apart..

Answer (score 0):

The first default statement of a concrete class constructor is `super();` calling statement.

So, to make it work, you either remove

```
public RustyChain()
{
 weight = 8.0f;
}
```

or add a no-arg constructor in the super class like this

```
public SunkenObject()
{}
```